# Centering a page with a 3-column layout

Tags: html, css

I'm having problems with my page's layout. I'm trying to do a header, 3-column, footer layout, all centered. Here is my code:

css:

```
#pgCenter
{
    text-align:center;
    margin: 20px;
}

#container
{
    text-align:left;
    width: 850px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#container #header
{
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

#container #col1
{
    width: 250px;
    float: left;
}

#container #col2outer
{
    width: 600px;
    float:right;
}

#col2outer #col2mid
{
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
}

#col2outer #col2side
{
    width: 300px;
    float: right;
}

#container #footer
{
    text-align:center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

html:

```
<body>
  <div id="pgCenter">
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="container">
      <div id="header">
        here is my header
      </div>
      <div id="col1">
        This is where the login control goes. For testing purposes, I'll just throw some text in here.
      </div>
      <div id="col2outer">
        <div id="col2mid">
          <p>INSIDE DIV ID:col2mid - And here is some more placehold text so that I can see how this div is laying out!
            I should also write some more text here because I still don't see anything going on :(</p>
        </div>
        <div id="col2side">
          <p>INSIDE DIV ID:col2side - What else do you want me to put? I can't even think of anything right now except
            eating some bomb delicious wingstop. I can't wait to get my paws on those saucy spicy cajun flavored mudda fuggas!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="footer">
        <p>(footer) Copyright © 2011</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

The problem I'm having is that the header and footer content want to show up above and below either the first or outer (`col2outer`) columns, based on the size of its content, instead of all the columns in a neatly stacked fashion. This `col2outer div` also appears 1 `<br/>` lower than the first column.

I've looked at several posts here and elsewhere and can't find the right help. I'm not very good at css and would love any advice and tips I can get on best practice, what I'm doing wrong, etc. Thank you very much.

PS - please excuse my placeholding text hehe.

Comment: clear:both in the footer css?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve the first problem, you just need to add `clear: both` to `#container #footer`, to clear the floats above it.

The `#container #col2outer` problem is because the `p` elements inside have some `margin` set by default.

Also, you should drop the extraneous `#container` from the start of all of the selectors.

With all of those changes: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/z4U3d/

Comment: Thx thirtydot. How do you know where to clear the floats? I tried doing this in my `container` div, as it mentioned in other posts. This isn't the first time you've helped me clearing floats, hehe. Wish I had a solid understanding of this darn thing. And the `p` solved it.. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

use overflow: hidden:
http://jsfiddle.net/zDbsQ/1/

[image]

Comment: Hahah. Well, overflow:hidden; in `col2mid`, still seeing the same results.

Comment: looks like you use IE or something. without browser version or screenshot i cant help more, sry. try clear: both for footer anyway.

Comment: You need to untick "Normalized CSS" in jsFiddle so that you can see the second mentioned problem in action.

Comment: sure. couse <p> tag by default have margin :) remove p tag or set p { margin: 0 }. thx for tip.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing way too much

```
    #pgCenter
    {
        text-align:center;
        margin: 20px;
    }

    #container
    {
        text-align:left;
        width: 960px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #header
    {
        width:100%;
        text-align:center;
    }


    #footer
    {
        text-align:center;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .oneThirdContainer {
        width: 300px;
        float: left;
    }

    .clear {
        clear: both;
    }
        </style>
      <div id="pgCenter">
      <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="container">
          <div id="header">
            here is my header
          </div>
          <div class="oneThirdContainer">
            <p>This is where the login control goes. For testing purposes, I'll just throw some text in here.</p>
          </div>

            <div class="oneThirdContainer">
              <p>INSIDE DIV ID:col2mid - And here is some more placehold text so that I can see how this div is laying out!
                I should also write some more text here because I still don't see anything going on :(</p>
            </div>
            <div class="oneThirdContainer">
              <p>INSIDE DIV ID:col2side - What else do you want me to put? I can't even think of anything right now except
                eating some bomb delicious wingstop. I can't wait to get my paws on those saucy spicy cajun flavored mudda fuggas!</p>
            </div>
          <div class="clear"></div>
          <div id="footer">
            <p>(footer) Copyright © 2011</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: @Ken do you know why `clear:both;` has to be in this location? In most posts that I've seen doing column floats, the `clear:both;` (or `overflow:auto/hidden;`) is located in the `container` div. How do you know where to put this damn thing?

Comment: The best way to explain it is like this, when you want elements to be side by side, you ask them to "float", now if you add a non floated element immediately after the floated elements you'll get a lot of weird behavior. Think of clear:both as a new line. Its best to put a container around your floated elements and right before you close the container.

Comment: <div id="container"><div class="floatme"></div><div class="floatme"><div class="clear></div><div> regular stuff goes here</div>

Comment: Ok, cool. "Think of `clear:both;` as a new line." -That helps.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than try to point out what I see that's wrong with yours, I'll just show you how I would do it.

Essentially, you're describing 3 rows, the center row divided into 3 columns.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="header">header</div>
<div id="middle">
    <div id="col1">col 1</div>
    <div id="col2">col 2</div>
    <div id="col3">col 3</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">footer</div>
```

So, what you want to do is place the `header` and `footer` at a size that you're comfortable with, then allow the middle to take up space. As an example (and you'll want to adjust sizes):

```
/* CSS */
body {width:460px;}
body * {margin:0px; padding:0px;}
#header {width: 960px; max-width:960px; height:100px; border:1px solid black;}
#middle {width: 960px; max-width:960px; max-height:800px; border:1px solid black;}
#footer {width: 960px; max-width:960px; height:100px; border:1px solid black;}
#col1 {width:315px; height:100px; border:1px solid black; display:inline-block;}
#col2 {width:316px; height:100px; border:1px solid black; display:inline-block;}
#col3 {width:315px; height:100px; border:1px solid black; display:inline-block;}
```

That should put `col1`, `col2`, and `col3` inline within `middle`. I included borders only to exemplify their placement...

There you have it – simple three column layout. Not the most elegant, but it'll do. For more elegant ones, view:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/holygrail/